# possible assignment to two different entities

Tags: database, database-design, domain-driven-design

Let's say I have a carrier which can be composed of drivers and dispatchers or just a single owner-operator that does it all. Both drivers and owner-operators can be assigned to a trip. What should my trip table design look like? Should I just have both an `assigned_to_owner_operator_id` and `assigned_to_driver_id` which can be nullable?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't an "owner-operator" a driver in context of a trip? Are you sure both definitions (an owner-operator and a driver) live in the same bounded context?

Cars driven by drivers, right?

Comment: yes but the owner-operator doesn't have a driver record - should I have to create one?

Comment: I guess I'm wondering more generally is if you have multiple different types of actors who can be assigned to a particular entity how this should be handled. Do you just use a user or group ID? This would be easier to solve in a graph db.

Comment: @Jordan, you can "map" entities from one context to the entities of the second one. Ubiquitous languages in these contexts are most likely different.

F.ex., you can have a "user" in Security context who might be an "operator" in the CustomerRequests context and a "driver" in the Trip context. All these entities have sense only in their own bounded contexts\domains.

You should design your domain in technology-agnostic manner. Domain first, technologies after. At least this is one of the main rules authors in every DDD book.

I'm looking at one of you tags so can misunderstand you, sorry